# Как исправить ложное отображение ошибок в Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qtcreator

Я создал обычное приложение Qt Widgets и оно компилируется самим Qt Creator и работает, но Qt Creator видит ошибки там где их нету(в приложении не поменялось даже строчки кода).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://evileg.com/ru/forum/topic/856/

Comment: Я переустановил с сайта а не через терминал, и все исправилось. Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло переустановка qtcreator на Ubuntu с сайта - https://www.qt.io/offline-installers.

Через переустановку (sudo apt install qtcreator) qtcreator отказывался корректно работать.